# Set a specific middleware in laravel

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

I am working on a Laravel Application, in this application every user can have multiple roles, there are 12 roles in this application which one user can have at least one of them at a time or many of them, what I want is when user wants to login I want to show him/her the available roles that he/she can login with and he/she should select on of his roles to login, I have one Middleware for every role which can be set for him/her, the problem is that I can't set a specific middleware  for user while login.
one of middlewares:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CTDMiddleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $role = Auth::user()->user_role[0]->role->role;
            if (strtolower($role) == \App\Classes\User_Groups::$ctd) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
        return redirect()->route('/logout');
    }

}
```

Here I just checked the first role of user while she may have many more roles.
Login Controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller {
use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function login(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make(
                        array(
                    'email' => $request->email,
                    'password' => $request->password
                        ), array(
                    'email' => 'required | email',
                    'password' => 'required',
                        )
        );
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('admin/login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        } else {
            $adminInfo = array("email" => $request->email, "password" => $request->password); 
            if (auth()->attempt($adminInfo)) {
                return redirect('/home');
            } else {
                return redirect('/login')->with('errors', new \PhpParser\Error('Not Found', array('email', 'password')));
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        auth()->logout();
        return view('auth/login');
    }

}
```

however I didn't implemented the role selection option yet, but in login controller I want to call to attempt() for a specific Middleware.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with a specific guard like this:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($adminInfo, $request->get('remember'))
```

Comment: I have tried but it is not working, it redirects me back to the login page

Comment: I have tried but it is not working, it redirects me back to the login page

Comment: before using a specific guard you have to do some config like edit the config/auth.php by define the guard the driver and the provider have you did it?

Comment: before using middleware I have tried using guards, the guards were not setting correctly in even not getting logout, here are my guards and providers in auth.php:

Comment: 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'ctd' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'ctds',
        ],
        'pm' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'pms',
        ],
        'prm' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'prms',
        ],
    ],

Comment: 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'fms' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'pms' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'hrms' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'sms' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],

Comment: I have a guard and provider for every user-group or user-role, I couldn't load all of them because of commenting limit here.

Comment: you have to define the constructor and specify the middleware and the guard you want to use like this public funcfion __contruct(){ $this->middleware('auth:admin')}

Comment: Thank you, Very Much, You were right, I fixed it now it is working.